# C#: ServiceController.Stop() not stopping service dependencies

Tags: c#, windows, service, process

From what I understood, stopping a service instance via a Service Controller should be synonymous with stopping a service via Windows Services. Then, should stopping a service also stop it's dependencies, as this would happen manually stopping a service in Windows Services?

Or is there something programatically I have to account for? e.g iterating through the services dependencies & stopping them individually as well?

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks

Comment: stopping service never stops its dependencies...

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245230/how-to-programmatically-stop-a-service-and-its-dependencies

Comment: @Steve; therefore to stop the dependencies, you'd have to stop them individually? (via C#)

Comment: the only things that stop when you stop are the service itself and anything dependant on it - whether you do it in c# or just right click stop in service manager.